# How to auto logout when goes to special url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logout

In laravel, now I hope to know this problem.

I try to reset password in logout status and the problem is it's redirect automatically to dashboard page if I logged in already.

So I hope to know how to logout and goes to special url such as reset password url from my received mail.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Auth vendor. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication. After this in route file put all routes under authentication where you want user to be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 5+ :

create a middleware for your route and check your access condition in this middleware, if your route passes the condition then it will show your desired page.